# How to get the values of both date selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"/>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'center'
      }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      });
    });
    </script>
```

I have a problem on taking the value of both the date selected.

Comment: Do you have any more errors, what is not working?

Comment: It works perfectly for me too, but what I want is to get the value of the date selected and display in another page.

Comment: Your 3x comments about getting it in another page are not in the question; there's no way anyone could know that's what you were actually after.  Please **ask the question that you want an answer to**.   Not some other random, semi-related question.  (you can also normally edit the above, though in this case there are answers to your question as asked, so I suggest you accept an answer that answers the question **as asked** and ask a new question).

Comment: @SimonTeoh Are you using any backend? If not after submit you can store the values in the local storage (eg for forms) or as query param (eg for a search). If you use backend rendering you can submit to the backend and display the data on the next page. Without knowing the context of your project it is hard to tell which way is the best solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned what errors you have come across, what I can suggest you is to make sure you have imported the necessary scripts from bootstrap datepicker library. Also,  if the scripts and the css links are not in proper order you might get errors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works perfectly for me too, but what I want is to get the value of the date selected and display in another page.

Comment: @SimonTeoh if you want to display it on another page, you have to use backend language such as C# or any other that provides a mechanism to display one page's information to another. This mechanism is named as Session. You can google it up 'Sessions in C#' 

Because this is practically impossible to show using JavaScript/Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works perfectly for me. Please make sure you have imported all the required libraries. See a working example here.

**Required Libraries.**

1. jquery.min.js
2. moment.js
3. daterangepicker.js
4. daterangepicker.css

I think you might have missed `moment js` library.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
    {
      opens: "center",
    },
    function(start, end, label) {
      console.log(
        "A new date selection was made: " + start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + " to " + end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      );
      $("#selected-date").text("A new date selection was made: " + start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + " to " + end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    },
  );
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      name="daterange"
      value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018"
      style="width:100%;text-align:center;"
    />
 Selected Date <p id="selected-date"></p>
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me too, but what I want is to get the value of the date selected and display in another page.

Comment: @SimonTeoh You can make use of jQuery selector for the same.